# Bluesmirf HID iOS App - Bluetooth Door lock/unlock

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, arduino

I'm running into a hurdle and not too sure how to tackle it, looking for some help :). I'm trying to make a door lock/unlock mechanism using and arduino UNO and Bluesmirf HID (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10938). I know similar products already exist that will do all the background work for me but I'm doing this for my own education and iOS app development experience.

Iphone bluetooth profiles are listed on this site (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204387). Since the Iphone5 does not support SPP (serial port profile) for bluetooth, my only logical choice is the HID profile (using another profile wouldn't make sense to me but I could be wrong?)

The Bluesmirf HID can operate on many different profiles, including SPP, but I've configured it to HID as that is the only profile that makes sense to me for Iphone communciation? The issue I run into though is that the bluetooth module ONLY communicates to the arduino via serial (rx/tx). So my question then becomes, is it possible to develop an app (setup for HID) that will eventually send critical serial data to the arduino to properly actuate the lock/unlock mechanism on the door? Is this even possible and what other road blocks may I run into?

As for the app development portion, I was planning to start with the apple example of temp/humidity. I THINk it uses BLE setup but I'll need to confirm. Once I got a handle on this I was going to start writing my own code. The ideal GUI I'm looking for would have connect, lock and unlock buttons that basically send data to the bluesmirf module and toggle a GPIO. I can add more features later on like security, etc...

Thanks in advance for any feedback. If this needs to be posted on another forum please let me know!

Comment: The HID profile is Human Interface Device - on iOS this means a keyboard, so you can send data from the Bluesmirf but it will appear as keystrokes. You cannot send data to the Bluesmirf because you can't send data *to* a keyboard.  You need to find something else that supports BLE GATT for use with core Bluetooth.  The LightBlue bean is good - http://wilko.me/wordpress/?p=256

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok so the HID portion makes complete sense. I guess I thought there may have been a way to create an app that utilizes the HID portion of the phone and bluesmirf to send serial data to the arduino. It doesn't sound like it...

So I am curious now, there is another product (http://redbearlab.com/bleshield/) that is bluetooth and it handles all of the communication to the arduino. They also have a pre-built app to do all the GPIO toggles manually. Do you have any idea what they have their bluetooth module setup as? I was assuming HID but I really have no idea now.

Also what is GATT?

Comment: GATT is the general attribute profile. It is what is supported by Core Blietooth. Essentially it allows 'variable' (called characteristics) to be exchanged. Many BLE modules emulate a serial port using a pair of characteristics - one you write to and the device sends it out of the hardware serial port.  The other you read from and it will give you any data that has been received by the hardware serial port. The red bear module is slightly different but still uses gatt

Comment: Ah Ok. I have never heard of GATT it until reading your post so I have some research to do now. And the Core Bluetooth statement you mentioned, that is internal to iOS correct?

Comment: Core Bluetooth is the framework that you use on iOS to talk to Bluetooth Low Energy devices, although one of the nice parts of the LightBlue bean is that it comes with an iOS ask that hides a lot of that. It also has the arduino on board

Comment: @Paulw11 - So I'm looking for some more advice if you have a minute. I've been looking at the Lightblue Bean on Punch Through's website and I cannot find any documentation as to which bluetooth profile the device uses. I'm just trying to compare the RN-42 module vs the one they made to see what the difference in and how I know in the future what devices are compatible w/ Iphone apps and which ones aren't. Does that make sense? Do you have a minute to explain where to find that content or how I should go about searching for it? Thanks again for the help and explaining all of this!

Comment: The bean uses the GATT profile as do most BLE devices. This I supported by Core Bluetooth but Punchthrough also have an iOS framework that builds on top of Core Bluetooth and makes it easy to use the Bean's features.